# Change the top links URL in a custom third party theme

Tags: theme, toplinks

I have to change the URL for "Placanje" link so it points to (http://localhost/darnik/customer/account/create/) instead of the current one. Please see the attachment with the template and block hints.
[image]

the two links are added in class Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links but I don't know in which moment they are added, so that I can change the specifics for each one. How can I find where these links are added to the block?

I used this advice:

```
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way
```

and I managed to add another link in the top links which now points to `/customer/account/create/`. But I can't remove the old one "Placanje" which has URL `/checkout` I tried to use the `<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>/checkout</url></action>` but it won't remove it. Where else can I look to remove this?

Comment: Have you checked local.xml within your theme?

Comment: Nothing of interest there.

Comment: I checked app/etc/local.xml and nothing of interest is there.

Comment: These may be the default links to change you may need to add some xml in there.

Comment: https://www.classyllama.com/blog/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/theme217k/layout/local.xml - also nothing.

Comment: Have a look at that blog article i was going to try and write that out in answer but seems all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the checkout link is set within **checkout.xml**:

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

So to remove this you could add below to your **local.xml** within the **default** node:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
</reference>
```

I have tested this and it worked for me but removed both the checkout and cart links in **Magento 1.9.3.1** running the default **RWD** theme. I'm not sure you need the cart link in your theme but i overcome them both dissapearing with **local.xml** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
   <default>
     <reference name="top.links">
       <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
       <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_updated">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

As stated in my comments there is a decent post about adding **top links** here:

http://www.classyllama.com/blog/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Am unsure why the remove by url is not working, did you try "checkout" rather than "/checkout"? This could be something to do with the actual url that is used for checkout not actually being **checkout** and being **/checkout/onepage/index** or something along those lines but now i'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I didn't try to reinstate the other link though, client didn't ask for it.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.